# Adding characters to the beginning and end of a line starting with a specific string

Tags: command-line, sed, grep, replace

I have quite a few html files where I need to comment out a specific line of JavaScript:

```
<script src="/common/javascript/jquery/jquery.tools-1.2.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

What I would like to do via command line, is search .htm files in the directory for the string: "/common/javascript/jquery/jquery.tools-1.2.4.min.js" and add `<!--` to the beginning of the respective line containing the string, and 
`-->` to the end of the line.

Some files include `type=` and some do not, which is why I'd like to search using the src value and add to the beginning and end of line.

Thanks for the help. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
for f in *.htm*; do
  mv "$f" "$f.tmp"
  sed 's#^\(.*common/javascript/jquery/jquery.tools-1.2.4.min.js.*\)#<!-- \1 -->#' "$f.tmp" > "$f"
  rm "$f.tmp" ;
done
```

Answer (score 1):

This will output a modified file if you replace "that whole line" with that entire js line you want to comment out.

`sed 's/\(that whole line\)/<<!--\1-->/' file.htm`

Now just iterate that over all the files in the dir

`for f in *htm; do
   sed 's/\(that whole line\)/<<!--\1-->/' $f > $f.new
done`

I'll let you figure out how to handle moving them back to the right filenames. (Maybe a new dir? Maybe a `mv` command? Whatever's best in your situation.)

Comment: Oh sorry, I just realized this isn't right because not all the lines are identical.